# how to insert into more than one mysql table in single query?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have this query which on executing in my sql command line client executes fine and get entry in both tables but executing it gives me error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the man
>   ual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tm_belonging(B
>   ID,BELONGING_TYPE,BELONGING_TEXT)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID' at line 1

```
String sql="INSERT INTO tm_visitor(VISITOR_TEXT,COMPANY_TEXT,CONTACT,PERSON_TO_MEET,DEPARTMENT_TEXT,FLOOR)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?);"+"INSERT INTO tm_belonging(BID,BELONGING_TYPE,BELONGING_TEXT)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?,?);";

PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1,VisitorName.toUpperCase());
pst.setString(2,Company.toUpperCase());
pst.setString(3,Contact);
pst.setString(4,WhomeToMeet.toUpperCase());
pst.setString(5,Department);
pst.setString(6,DepartmentFloor);
pst.setString(7,BType);
pst.setString(8,Belonging);
pst.executeUpdate();    
pst.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm try this:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO tm_visitor(VISITOR_TEXT,COMPANY_TEXT,CONTACT,PERSON_TO_MEET,DEPARTMENT_TEXT,FLOOR)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?);"+"set @lastid=LAST_INSERT_ID();"+"INSERT INTO tm_belonging(BID,BELONGING_TYPE,BELONGING_TEXT)VALUES(@lastid,?,?);";
```

if this dont work you must use one prepared statement for query

Comment: well pablo....would you explain this statement in your query...
`"set @lastid=LAST_INSERT_ID();"`

Comment: The statement is for setting a variable in mysql. I think is better calculate all the values before the insert, not to calculate at the insert (and in this case works xD)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can. You have to use two prepared statements for two insert queries. Normally i create store procedure if I have to deal with more than one table in one transaction and use callable statement.

Comment: Thanks sandeep it worked.
but do you think this a best approach using two prepared statements for inserting to more than one table.

Comment: @yatin: It is good practice to accept the most helpful answer